# Adding a request heeader in jax filter using ContainerRequestContext but on retrieving using @Context httpservlet request is coming as null

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs, servlet-filters

Hi I added a request header in the incoming request in the jax-rs filter using `ContainerRequestContext` but when I am retrieving that header in the controller from `@Context HttpServletRequest` it is coming as null which means the header was not found but if I use `@HeaderParam("header_name)` or `@Context httpHeaders` to retrieve it I am able to get the header value,

I was of the opinion that on making any change in the request using `ContainerRequestContext` would reflect in `HttpServletRequest` as well ? Is this understanding incorrect ?

If any one else also faced this issue and was able to resolve it, any help would be appreciated

I tried to get the header value from `HttpServletRequest` but I was not able to get it

I was able to get the value using `@HeaderParam("header_name)` or`@Context httpHeaders`

I had expected to get the header value from `HttpServletRequest.getHeader` as well, and if it is not supposed to work I want to know the reason behind it and what is the best practice to get a header value ?

Comment: _" Is this understanding incorrect ?_ - YES